# How to remove default style of header in wordpress metabox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the problem which when I create a header in my wordpress plugin metabox, it always apply the default style on my header:
[image]

even when I apply, my own style, `<h3 style="background-color: black; color:blue">Text Block Settings</h3>`, it only changes the text color but not the background color, why??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a [CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) issue although without access to the source code I can't tell what's going on.

Since it seems like you want a very hack-ey fix, try `<h3 style="background:black !important; color:blue">Text Block Settings</h3>` and see if that works (normally you should avoid using `!important` but if this is a one-off override it can be alright).